# using service in different controllers files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-services, angular-controller

Service - optionService.js
controllers - app.js & welcomeCtrl.js & otherCtrl.js

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mainapp', ['mainapp.welcome','optionServiceModule']);
app.controller('mainappCtrl', function ($scope,optionService) {
   optionService.fetchOptionDetails().success(function(response){
        $scope.option = response;
   });
});
```

**welcomeCtrl.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('mainapp.welcome', ['optionServiceModule']);

    app.controller('welcomeCtrl',[function($scope,optionService) {
        optionService.fetchOptionTwoDetails().success(function(response){
            $scope.OptionTwo = response;
        });
    }]);
```

**optionService.js**

```
var app = angular.module('optionServiceModule',[]);

app.factory('optionService',['$http',function($http) {
  var obj = {};

    obj.fetchOptionDetails = function(){ 
        return $http.get('localhost/api/option/optionOne');
    }

    obj.fetchOptionTwoDetails = function(){
        return $http.get('localhost/api/option/optionTwo');
    }
 return obj;
}]);
```

optionService is working fine in app.js but 
giving error in WelcomeCtrl.js

**Error**

```
Cannot read property 'fetchOptionTwoDetails' of undefined
```

wanna know how to use a service in multiple controller file ?

Thank you In Advance

Comment: Are you minifying the code?

Comment: Not yet.. but will be after completion of application @ RaghuVenmarathoor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inject the `$scope` and `optionService` to controller as string like this

```
app.controller('welcomeCtrl',['$scope','optionService',function($scope,optionService) {
        optionService.fetchOptionTwoDetails().success(function(response){
            $scope.OptionTwo = response;
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Sachilaranawanka

Comment: @Insane noise no prob. make sure to mark as answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/v5aym4ej/3/)

**Js code**

```
  var app1 = angular.module('mainapp.welcome', ['optionServiceModule']);
  app1.controller('welcomeCtrl', function($scope, optionService) {
    optionService.fetchOptionTwoDetails().success(function(response) {
      $scope.OptionTwo = response;
    });
  });
```

you added [] but forgot add dependecies

Comment: where did i forget to add dependencies @JayantPatil

Comment: this is updated code plz add this code and test your app

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @jayantpatil I tried this and it giving same error **SORRY**

Comment: try to see link